# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. NodeJS and AngularJS App

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cors

I have read all the above links but it still doesn't solve my issue.
Node code

```
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
    let allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:8080', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'];
    let origin = req.headers.origin;
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
        console.log(origin);
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080');
    }
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE");
    next();
});
```

angularJS

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
});
```

I am actually hitting the url and it returns me 200 OK response as well, but it still fails with such a message. I have tried a lot of blogs and answers on SO but none seems to help and each one reiterates the same thing which I have already tried. 
Message it fails with

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5040/save. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only predict one issue here.

> Your app.use(), must be above all the requests.

I have already burnt my hands over this kind of issue So I know. Let me know if it helps. If not, we will start over.

Answer (score 0):

Download a Chrome plugin called **Cors** from here:
`https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en`

It will allow you to request any site with ajax from any source.